# tvOS PlayPause button tap gesture on AVPlayerViewController

Tags: swift, avfoundation, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I have added a tapGestureRecognizer for the Play/Pause button and it works on a custom player (meaning a AVPlayer inserted in a ViewController instance) as such:

```
lazy var playPauseButtonTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped))
    gesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPress.PressType.playPause.rawValue)]
    return gesture
}()

@objc private func playPauseTapped() {
    print("HELLO PLAY PAUSE TAPPED")
    togglePlayPause()
}
private func togglePlayPause() {
    switch avPlayer.timeControlStatus {
    case .playing:
        avPlayer.pause()
    case .paused:
        avPlayer.play()
    case .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate:
        break
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    avPlayer.play()

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(playPauseButtonTap)
}
```

This works! But when the same code is run on a class that inherits from AVPlayerViewController (except the part where we insert the AVPlayerLayer because AVPlayerViewController handles that part), when the button is tapped to pause, the gesture recognizer code won't get called, when the button is tapped to play/resume it DOES get called.

I need to know when the user pauses playback. Is there any way to get this to work using the AVPlayerViewController?

I'm not looking to do swizzling or use any private APIs as Apple will not take that lightly however, I'd be interested to learn if anyone has made it work using some hacky solution that way.

NOTE: I also found out if you have this call: `UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` in your app, this makes a gesture recognizer completely ignore the play/pause button taps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe `AVPlayerRateDidChangeNotification`'s `AVPlayerRateDidChangeReasonKey` will give you enough information. `AVPlayerRateDidChangeReasonSetRateCalled` might correlate with play/pause taps. Note: this is just an augmented KVO on `AVPlayer.rate` I believe

Comment: Ohhh, that's an interesting idea. I'll give this a try and report back! Thanks so much. If it works, I'll put back the bounty and you can have it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track `timeControlStatus` of the `AVPlayer` you should observe it with Key-Value Observing instead of handling gestures etc. because AVPlayerViewController has other buttons.

```swift
import AVKit

let observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

let url = URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8")!
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
player.play()

let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player

observer = player.observe(\.timeControlStatus, options: [.new]) { player, change in
  switch player.timeControlStatus {
    case .paused:
      print("paused")

    case .playing:
      print("playing")
      
    case .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate:
      print("waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate")
      
    @unknown default:
      break
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = playerController
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

> NOTE: `observer` variable must be stored anywhere on your controller or globally.

Comment: Thanks, actually yea I thought of an observer too but in my case this won't work. I'm basically trying to specifically know when the user uses the play/pause button to show an ad. If they don't use the play/pause or the middle button tap to pause, I don't want to show the ad. That's the reason. Another way the content gets paused is if the user holds down the left/right arrow to scrub. Don't want t show an ad in that case either. Thanks for the idea & help.